# traceroute timing out in hop 5 for hostname

Tags: centos, timeout, hostname, dedicated-server, networking

For some reason, traceroute to hostname (and any domains hosted on this server) always times out on hop 5, right between the two shown below:

```
76.246.22.2
(Request timed out.)
ggr7.sffca.ip.att.net [12.122.114.17]
```

The tracert eventually completes at hop 16. The addresses are all unique, and the timed out hop only occurs on hop 5. After the att.net, the hops are all some long hostname at above.net, before finally resolving to another IP, and then, finally, the hostname.

1) What does this timeout effect?

2) Is there anything I can do about this - or it something I've misconfigured? Dedicated CentOS/WHM server.

(The other IP's assigned to the same machine works without this timeout...)

Comment: tracert now takes 20 hop's to reach wanted hostname destination..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just because router that is on Hop 5 is filtering traceroute request.
It's not a problem, there is no impact for your server and you can't do anything about this.

Comment: Is it better if I request a different IP to be used for the hostname? (one that doesn't time out in mid-hop...)

Comment: How? Unless you move to another hoster, the other IP will use the same infrastructure, i.e. also go through that router.

Comment: I notice that there are other IP addresses from the same provider that don't have the request timed out hop..

Comment: no inac, you really don't have to care about that. It's just normal. No worry

Comment: The fact that hop 5 times out means almost nothing to you. Hop 5 is simply ignoring or discarding your tracert packets. The fact that your tracert continues on beyond hop 5 tells you that the path is OK.